# How to empty the datastore in sencha?

Tags: sencha-touch

I am new to sencha touch. I have a datastore and i want to empty the datastore when the back button is clicked. Is there any method like refresh used to empty the datastore? Can anyone show me a bit of code on it?

This is not working in my case:

```
{
   text: 'Back',
   ui: 'back',
   width: 50,
   handler: function() {
       var records = iPolis.journalListStore.getRange();
       iPolis.journalListStore.remove(records);

       iPolis.Viewport.setActiveItem('journalPanel', {
            type: 'slide',
            direction:'right'
       });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `store.getRange();` to get all records of an `Ext.data.Store` and then pass those records to `store.remove();` function to remove it form store

```
var records = store.getRange();
store.remove(records);
```

Comment: if you want to remove all record then you can use store.removeAll();

Comment: removeAll is only available in sencha touch 2 not in 1.1, check documentation

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a solution to my question, i will post it here maby it will help someone.
the problem is that the store was not loaded so i have to getRange after the store load, here is the code :

```
     StoreTrajectoire.on('load',function(store,records,opts){
        var points = [];
        points =StoreTrajectoire.getRange();
     }
```

this will return an array of objects, to read the array data :

```
    for(var i = 0; i < store.getCount(); i++ ) {
    var record = store.getAt(i);
    var data = record.get('your attribue')
    points.push(p);
    console.log(points[i]);
    }
```

wish that can help you.